# how to access Cmis without a password?

Tags: c#, alfresco, ntlm, cmis, dotcmis

I'm trying to query Alfresco through cmis with DotCmis ( http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html )

It's working ok as long as I specify a user / password.

How can I do that without specifying a password ? I'd like to use the CurrentIdentity or something but I can't...

```
parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://server/alfresco/service/cmis";
parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "user";
parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "password";
```

Through the Apache documentation, it seems you can use a CmisBindingFactory for ntlm but dotCmis does not support it I think.
I know nothing of java / apache so I'm awfully lost here.

Can it be achieved ? or is there any other library you may suggest ?

A real big thank you if you can help !!

Comment: Do you want to perform an anonymous (guest) request, or are you trying to do some sort of single sign-on magic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I submitted a patch to DotCmis and now the latest build works with Ntlm.
This was tested on my side on Alfresco.

Sorry it took me too long to answer here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the patch! To be clear, this is for NTLM-based SSO (Alfresco passthru + ldap-ad), not for Kerberos-based SSO, right?

Answer (score 2):

not sure that this will help out but:

dotCMIS will support in the next version (0.5) NTLM, for 0.4 you could downoad the Patch
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-531
or get the whole source from trunk
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/chemistry/dotcmis/trunk/

Answer (score 2):

DotCMIS 0.5 has been released, so thanks to Vincent it should work out-of-the-box now :-)

Sample code:

```
// Parameters.
Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
parameters[SessionParameter.AtomPubUrl] = "http://yourserver:port/alfresco/cmisatom"; // Change this to yours.
parameters[SessionParameter.BindingType] = BindingType.AtomPub;
parameters[SessionParameter.AuthenticationProviderClass] = "DotCMIS.Binding.NtlmAuthenticationProvider";

// No need for username and password, thanks to NTLM-based SSO (Single Sign On)
//parameters[SessionParameter.User] = "<username>";
//parameters[SessionParameter.Password] = "<password>";

SessionFactory factory = SessionFactory.NewInstance();
ISession session = factory.GetRepositories(parameters)[0].CreateSession();

// List all children of the root folder.
IFolder rootFolder = session.GetRootFolder();
foreach (ICmisObject cmisObject in rootFolder.GetChildren())
{
    Console.WriteLine(cmisObject.Name);
}
```

Please note the `AuthenticationProviderClass` line.
Make sure to NOT define username and password, otherwise it will not work.

[Full working sample C# solution](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/DotCmisNtlmSample/blob/master/DotCmisNtlmSample/Program.cs).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CMIS. From your codes, it looks like that parameters are not passed to the server. Do you need to do it differently by adding parameters? For example,

```
parameters.add(value, key....);
```

Comment: There should be a ntlm parameterI think  : http://chemistry.apache.org/java/0.7.0/maven/apidocs/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/client/bindings/CmisBindingFactory.html#NTLM_AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDER but it's not implemented in dotCMIS as far as I studied it and I don't have knowledge on how to add it

Answer (score 0):

> in WS-Security (UsernameToken)  is enabled by default and a username
>   and a password have to be provided. Try to disable WS-Security
>
> i am not familiar with the CMIS
>
> check it here.. might help
>
> https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/chemistry/content/opencmis-client-bindings.html

Comment: I don't think you can do that and I can't login manually through a webservice either